# displaying phone number with array

Tags: php, arrays

I don't know how to do the following operation:

**Operation:** Using the following code, it displays the phone number by accessing database using SQL queries.

```
<?php
include_once('includes/config.php');
include_once('includes/class.db.php');
$database = new DB();
$sql=$database->get_results("SELECT table_url,phone_no FROM allstatevan");
//print_r($sql); exit;
foreach($sql as $key=>$value) {
    if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == $value['table_url']) {
        echo $value['phone_no'];
    }
}
?>
```

It works, but now I want to do the same operation using **arrays**.

**Note :** The table has 3 columns: `id`, `table_url` (having urls), and `phone_no` (having phone numbers)

This is the data inside the table:

```
$urls = array("http://www.example.com/contact-us.html","http://www.example1.com/moving-broker.html","http://www.example2.com/reviews","http://www.example3.com/corporate-moving.html","http://www.example4.com/long-distance-moving.html","http://www.example5.com/");
$phone = array("987.654.3210","012.345.6789","588.654.4548","798.215.1564","635.472.8754","800.741.6837");
```

Comment: Not able to understand clearly

Comment: And what is `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` that matches `$value['table_url']`

Comment: @Sunil Pachlangia: I want to do the above operation using arrays. I done the operation using database. How to do in arrays?

Comment: Are you sure that these arrays will be fix and what will be the value of $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Comment: @Uchila : $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] is used to get the current url and $value['table_url'] is the value getting from the table.

Comment: @Sunil Pachlangia: $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] is used for getting the current url

Comment: I know very well what is it used for i am asking the value in your case of $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Comment: In my case it returns http://www.example.com/contact-us.html and so on.

Comment: Post the values of `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

Comment: 1.) http://www.allstatevanlinesrelo.com/contact-us.html        
2.) http://www.allstatevanlinesrelo.com/moving-broker.html          
3.) http://www.allstatevanlinesrelo.com/reviews

Answer (score 1):

First search `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` in your array and get the index and map that index to phone  array.

```
$urls = array("http://www.example.com/contact-us.html","http://www.example1.com/moving-broker.html","http://www.example2.com/reviews","http://www.example3.com/corporate-moving.html","http://www.example4.com/long-distance-moving.html","http://www.example5.com/");
$phone = array("987.654.3210","012.345.6789","588.654.4548","798.215.1564","635.472.8754","800.741.6837");

$key = array_search($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $urls);
echo $phone[$key];
```

Output :

If `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is "http://www.example1.com/moving-broker.html"

```
$key = 2   ==> phone[2] = 012.345.6789
```